# download as PDF response from POST - AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm sending an AJAX POST request and I need to download the response that I'm receiving as PDF. I'm trying with this code that I have found online but it does nothing.

```
function testPdf(id){

  $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "pdf-creation/api/create-generate-pdf",
  data: JSON.stringify({documentId: id, Key: 724}),
  dataType: "json",
  contentType: "application/json",
  success: function(data){
    var blob = new Blob([data]);
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href=window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    link.download="testPdf.pdf";
    link.click();
  }
});

}
```

The response I am receiving from the API is like the one in picture.

[response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dIzZ6.png)

Thanks you all!

p.s.  No I cant switch to a GET request

Comment: what is code in your create-generate-pdf script ??

Comment: THe code in generate-pdf is backend made in Golang; I don't actually know what is because I'm not doing it. I just know that the response it gives me in the picture is correct, What I need to do Is to convert that blob and download it as pdf